# Cannot query "": Must be "" instance

Tags: django

I am pretty new to django as well as python, in my app i have two models one is `MyProfile` and One is `MyPost`, users will have a profile and users can create a post, it's all working but i wanted to show posts created by a user in their profiles. for that i tried creating a `get_context_data` inside my generic `Detailview`. But it gives me this error `Cannot query "ahmy": Must be "MyProfile" instance`. ahmy is my logged in username.

**My models**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, RegexValidator


# Create your models here.
class MyProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 500)
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    address = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="Male", choices=(("Male", 'Male'), ("Female", "Female"), ("LGBTQ", "LGBTQ")))
    phone_no = models.CharField(validators=[RegexValidator("^0?[5-9]{1}\d{9}$")], max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 240, null=True, blank=True)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = "image\\", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.user


class MyPost(models.Model):
    main_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = "image\\", null=True)
    amount_spend = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_donars = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    body = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    cr_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(to=MyProfile, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.title
```

**My View**
@method_decorator(login_required, name="dispatch")

```
class MyProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = MyProfile
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # Call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # Add in a QuerySet of all the user posts
        user_posts = MyPost.objects.filter(uploaded_by=self.request.user).order_by('-cr_date')
        context['user_posts'] = user_posts
        context['user'] = self.request.user
        return context
```

**My Html file**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="p-5">
<img src="/media/{{myprofile.pic}}" />
<h1 class="myhead2">{{myprofile.name}}</h1>
<p><strong>Address: {{myprofile.address}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>Phone Number: {{myprofile.phone_no}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>Email: {{myprofile.user.email}}</strong></p>
<p><strong>About:</strong> {{myprofile.purpose}}</p>
<p><strong> Total Donation Recived: {{myprofile.donation_recived}}</strong></p>
<hr>

<table class="table my-3">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
{% for MyPost in user_posts %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{MyPost.title}}</td>
            <td>{{MyPost.cr_date | date:"d/m/y"}}</td>
            <td>
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href='/covid/mypost/{{n1.id}}'>Read More</a>
            <a class="btn btn-dark btn-sm" href='/covid/mypost/delete/{{n1.id}}'>Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**URLS**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include
from covid import views
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
# Normal pages
    path('home/', views.HomeView.as_view()),
    path('tips/', views.TipsViews.as_view()),
    path('info/', views.InfoView.as_view()),
    path('dashboard', views.DashboardView.as_view()),
# Choose State URL
    path('chose_state', views.chose_state, name='chose_state'),
# Orginisations Profiles
    path('profile/edit/<int:pk>', views.MyProfileUpdateView.as_view(success_url="/covid/home")),
    path('myprofile/', views.MyProfileListView.as_view()),
    path('myprofile/<int:pk>', views.MyProfileDetailView.as_view()),
# Post URL
    path('mypost/create/', views.MyPostCreate.as_view(success_url="/covid/mypost")),
    path('mypost/delete/<int:pk>', views.MyPostDeleteView.as_view(success_url="/covid/mypost")),
    path('mypost/', views.MyPostListView.as_view()),
    path('mypost/<int:pk>', views.MyPostDetailView.as_view()),
    path('profile/edit/<int:pk>', views.MyProfileUpdateView.as_view(success_url="/covid/home")),
# Root URL
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url="home/")), 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `uploaded_by` field refers to a `MyProfile` model, not a `User` model. You can change the query to:

```
user_posts = MyPost.objects.filter(
    uploaded_by__user=self.request.user
).order_by('-cr_date')
```

So by using double underscores (`__`) we look "through" a relation, and we thus look for `MyPost` objects where the `uploaded_by` is a `MyProfile` with as `user` a reference to the `request.user` object.

If you want to display content of the user with the `pk` in the path:

```
path('myprofile/<int:pk>', views.MyProfileDetailView.as_view()),
```

you can replace this with:

```
user_posts = MyPost.objects.filter(
    uploaded_by_id=self.kwargs['pk']
).order_by('-cr_date')
```

given the `pk` is the *profile* id; or:

```
user_posts = MyPost.objects.filter(
    uploaded_by__user_id=self.kwargs['pk']
).order_by('-cr_date')
```

if the `pk` refers to the *user* id.

Or you can make use of `self.object`:

```
user_posts = self.object.mypost_set.order_by('-cr_date')
```

Comment: hey @Willem Van Onsen thanks for the answer, it solved the error but it is showing the post by the current user on the profile page of a different user, it should have shown the posts by profile page user.

Comment: @RakeshMajhi: can you show the relevant `url(..)` (with the a parameter of the user(name))?

Comment: hey @Willem Van Onsem i added my urls in my question please have a look.

Comment: @RakeshMajhi: see edit. I assume `pk` is the primary key of the *profile*, not the *user*?